# Embedded hasMany testing with Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to understand using Ember's hasMany. In particular, I'd like to be able to grab a particular object(s). I've tried grabbing `firstObject` on it but that doesn't work. And I've also tried looping over each object.

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/agarat/5/edit) and [jsBin with looping](http://jsbin.com/agarat/6/edit)

Important code:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  myOthers: DS.hasMany('App.MyOtherModel')
});

DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.MyModel',{
  myOthers: { embedded: 'always' }
});

App.MyOtherModel = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.store.load(App.MyModel, {
  id: 2,
  name: "myModel",
  my_others: [
    { name: 'myOther1' },
    { name: 'myOther1' }
  ]
});

console.log(myModel.get("myOthers.firstObject.name"));
```

I'm trying to do this for my tests, but I'm not having any luck.

How would I work with a `hasMany` relationship in order to grab a particular object and be able to loop over them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you have to go through the adapter, not the store.

[updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agarat/7/edit)

```
App.adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.create();
App.adapter.load(App.store, App.MyModel, {
  id: 2,
  name: "myModel",
  my_others: [
    { name: 'myOther1' },
    { name: 'myOther2' }
  ]
});
```